# jquery - unobtrusive validation javascript error on load - $jQval is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-javascript, unobtrusive-validation

I am using this with jquery 1.7. I keep getting - `jQval is undefined` error.

This is how i am loading the script.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
    dataType: "script",
    cache: true,
    success: callback
});
```

I also tried loading it directly in the head - same error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I don't suppose removing the back tick from before `type=` does anything, does it?

Comment: sorry that was just a typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
Cascading the ajax load calls solved it.. it looks like a timing issue on loading the two files

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8.1/jquery.validate.min.js",
       dataType: "script",
       cache: true,
       success: function () {
                        $.ajax({
                             url: "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                             dataType: "script",
                             cache: true,
                        });
                }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Just posting for anyone else getting here from a search...

The reason you were getting the error when loading the files in the head is that jquery.validate.unobtrusive requires jquery.validate. That's what was causing the error.

(ie, double-check that you're successfully including jquery.validate before jquery.validate.unobtrusive)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Thanks, you alleviated a lot of JS head scratching on my part.

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 scripts work great for me:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Assuming you have a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

typed to a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```